# Flutter/Dart: Passing this.variable as parameter

Tags: function, class, flutter, variables, dart

I have a list of profile fields that I would like to create using a single widget, but I'm new to Flutter and can't seem to work out one single thing: passing a variable through a parameter. I have been able to create many widgets that work just fine, using `this.variable = value`, but now that I'm trying to convert it to a single widget as not to repeat myself, that's where I'm having the problem.

I have the following code (of course removing all that I believe to be unnecessary). Here it currently shows an error of `The setter 'listType' isn't defined for the class '_ProfileDataState'.`

```
class _ProfileDataState extends State<ProfileData> {
  final _countries = DropDownLists.countries;
  String _country;
  var listType; //<-- added this per comments

  Widget profileDropDown(var list, var listType) {
    return Card(
      onTap: () async {
        AlertDialog(
          content: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            items: list.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            isDense: true,
            value: listType,
            onChanged: (value) {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                setState(() {
                  this.listType = value;
                });
              },
          )
        )
      }
    )
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return profileDropDown(_countries, _country),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class _ProfileDataState extends State<ProfileData> {
  String _country;
  var listType; // declare a variable

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listType = widget.listType; // assign it a value here
  }

  Widget profileDropDown(var listType) {
    return Card(
        onTap: () async {
          AlertDialog(
            onChanged: (value) {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              setState(() {
                this.listType = value; // works
              });
            },
          )
        }
    )
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, and the `listType = widget.listType;` is giving me an error now saying the getter is defined. I tried just including the empty variable up top without the init state, and I get a different error, probably having to do with a different variable, which is a list. I just updated my code here to show where I'm having the new issue, which is `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'`